# Why is this IF, OR, AND function not returning TRUE?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Why is this IF, OR, AND function not returning TRUE in A848?

See image below to view screen shot.

I'm using this algorithm to search for " not " and " valid", "not valid", and "invalid" in the colF-Body Column. Given that one of these words exist in colF - Body, if colD-Change in address is TRUE I want the algorithm to return FALSE and if FALSE to return TRUE.

Why is this approach returning FALSE in both instances?

The formula is entered into colA - INVALID

```
=IF(OR(
  AND( ISNUMBER( SEARCH(" not ",F2)+SEARCH(" valid",F2)), D848= "FALSE" ),
  AND( ISNUMBER( SEARCH("not valid",F2) ), D848 = "FALSE" ),
  AND( ISNUMBER( SEARCH("invalid",F2) ), D848 = "FALSE" )
),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9lSo.jpg

Comment: 1: Double check that the precedence of `and/or` boolean operators are in the correct order. Seems like they are, given the parentheses. 2: I believe the issue lies in the initial `=IF(OR(), "TRUE", "FALSE")` statement. Although, I'm too confused by the wording of your question and not familiar enough with Excel/VBS, much less you're specific task, to offer a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! Excel interprets FALSE and TRUE cells, even when entered as strings, as Boolean statements. When I was putting the quotes around the FALSE it was confusing Excel and didn't register the Boolean logic. When I took the quotes out it behaved as expected - returning TRUE when **only** FALSE.

Simplified logic:

```
=IF( AND( ISNUMBER( SEARCH("invalid",F849)), D849=FALSE), "TRUE", "FALSE")
```